# Scroll JavaFX ListView so item is in center

Tags: javafx-2

I want to scroll a ListView so that a selected item is in the center of the list (or as close to it as possible). Using `ListView#scrollTo` scrolls just enough so that the item is visible, so it always ends up at the top or bottom. I would like it to be centered in the list.

Comment: Do you want to scroll to the item at the center of `ListView`?

Comment: No, I want to scroll such that the selected item is in the center of the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. The solution I came up with was to use scrollTo to an earlier item on the list. I don't know when you want to scroll, in my case I was trying to scroll along with a for statement. So I placed a before variable outside the for and changed it with the for... At first the variable was null, and then I didn't scroll, latter it would have a value and then be scrolled to. You could compute the center the list by dividing the height of the list by the height of an element and then scroll to an element that was half of that value earlier...